# How to Calculate the Partial Derivative F_u(1,v) of the Integral Function F(u,v)

Tags: calculus, integration, derivatives, partial-derivative, leibniz-integral-rule

I'm working on a problem in calculus and am having difficulty with a specific function and its partial derivative. The function is defined as:

$F(u,v) = \int_{uv}^{u+v}e^{-(u-y)^2}dy$

I'm trying to calculate the partial derivative of this function with respect to $u$, evaluated at $u = 1$. Specifically, I'm looking to find $F'_u(1,v)$.

The correct answer is $(1-v) e^{-(1-v)^2}$

### What I've Tried:

- I understand that the process involves applying the Leibniz rule for differentiating under the integral sign.
- I've attempted to differentiate inside the integral, but I'm unsure if I'm applying the rule correctly, especially with the changing limits of integration.

### My Question:

Could someone help me understand the correct process for finding $F'_u(1,v)$?
I'm particularly interested in:

- The correct application of the Leibniz rule in this context.
- Any special considerations that arise due to the limits of integration being functions of $u$ and $v$
- Detailed steps or explanations would be greatly appreciated, as I'm looking to understand the process thoroughly.

Thank you in advance for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Since you are only interested in the differential w.r.t. $u$, we may regard $v$ as constant. So we'll omit the $v$ completely.  Temporarily, regard your $F$ as a function of three variables, and write
$$H(a,b,u) = \int_{a}^b g(u,y) dy$$
where $g(u,y) = e^{-(u-y)^2}$. Then your function in question is
$$F(u) = \int_{a(u)}^{b(u)} g(u,y)dy = H(a(u),b(u),u).$$
where $a(u) = uv$ and $b(u) = u+v.$
Note that
\begin{align*}
&H_a = -g(u,a)\\
&H_b = g(u,b)\\
&H_u = \int_a^b g_u(u,y) dy.
\end{align*}
By the chain rule,
\begin{align*}
F_u(u) = H_a(a(u),b(u),u) \cdot a_u(u) + H_b (a(u),b(u),u) \cdot b_u(u) + H_u(a(u),b(u),u).
\end{align*}
Can you take it from here?

Comment: I think I got you, but there must be a way to solve it without using a three variables function (because we haven't learned it, and it still was a question in the exam).

Comment: Another way would be to make the substitution $y = w+u$ to rewrite your integral as $F(u,v)= \int_{uv + u}^{2u+v} e^{-w^2} dw$. Perhaps this helps?